# How to measure tangly relationship of two variable distribution, comb or not?

Tags: python, statistics

Is there any statistic method to evaluate the tangly relationship of 2 distribution?

```
If 2 distribution are seperated clearly, result is bigger; 
if distributed like comb, result is smaller.


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.show()
```

[image]
2 distribution with different y-axis values[0,1]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have 2 categories, for which the distribution of the X-axis value is different. You could model each category separately (looks like the distribution of X in each category is not symmetrical, so you will want to use an asymmetric distribution, perhaps a gamma distribution or something like that) and then compute the Kullback-Leibler divergence between the per-category distributions. The greater the KL divergence, the greater the separation. Wikipdia will have a formula for KL divergence. There are probably other ways to approach this problem as well.